# why does a single core of a Spark worker complete each task faster than the rest of the cores in the other workers?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

I have three nodes in a cluster, each with a single active core. I mean, I have 3 cores in the cluster.

Assuming that all partitions have almost the same number of records, why does a single core of a worker complete each task faster than the rest of the cores in the other workers?

[image]

Please observe this screenshot. The timeline shows that the latency of the  worker core (x.x.x.230) is notably shorter than the other two worker core (x.x.x.210 and x.x.x.220) latencies.

This means that the workers x.x.x.210 and x.x.x.220 are doing the same job in a longer time compared to the worker x.x.x.230. This also happens when all the available cores in the cluster are used, but its delay is not so critial.

[image]

I submitted this application again. Look at this new screenshot. Now the fastest worker is the x.x.x.210. Observe that tasks 0, 1 and 2 process partitions with almost the same number of records. This execution time discrepancy is not good, is it?

I don't understand!!!

What I'm really doing is creating a DataFrame and doing a mapping operation to get a new DataFrame, saving the result in a Parquet file.

```
val input: DataFrame = spark.read.parquet(...)
val result: DataFrame = input.map(row => /* ...operations... */)
result.write.parquet(...)
```

Any idea why this happens? Is that how Spark operates normally?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Assuming that all partitions have almost the same number of records,_ - I am not sure how valid it is. Just based on the screenshot there is 4 fold difference between min and max shuffle size and significant difference in the number of output records.

Comment: Could you please also post the "Aggregated Metrics by Executor"? Is the number of output (or shuffled) records (roughly) the same?

Comment: I got the mean and the standard deviation for the records in all the partitions (Mean = 259 reacords per partition, Std = 1 records). Normally the single core in x.x.x.230 takes 11 minutes to compute a single task, while a single core in x.x.x.210/220 takes 34 minutes to compute a single task (a partition that has 265 records). It's crazy!!!